# Possessive pronoun + gerund confusion

Tags: syntactic-analysis, pronouns, gerunds, gerunds-vs-participles, software-bugs

I am confused over whether the following sentence contains a gerund and, therefore, whether I can precede that gerund with a possessive pronoun:

"I can't prevent your being offended."

Is "being" functioning as a gerund here? I'm starting to wonder if it's a present participle because "you" could work instead of "your" and when I type the sentence into Grammarly or Google Docs, it is flagged up as incorrect. But I think it's a noun that's the direct object of the verb "prevent"; it's the person's state of being offended that I can't prevent.

Comment: What's preventing you from asking those software platforms why their algorithms don't like what you've written? You should make them tell you what they want you to write. You can't ask us to solve software issues.

Comment: There are at least two orthogonal questions here: (1) Is "I can't prevent your being offended" good English, and (2) is "being" a gerund. Plus (3) Why doesn't Grammarly like it? There are plenty of examples indicating it's valid. "Prevent" can be followed by a verb phrase or a noun ("I can't prevent your departure") so maybe that's confusing Grammarly. You could even have "I can't prevent your being overriding my potential", and I'd love to know what Grammarly makes of that.

Comment: There's no gerund. "Your" is a genitive case NP, but it's not a determiner -- it's the subject of the "offended" clause.  Note that it can be replaced by nominative "you" with no change in meaning or loss of grammaticality.

Comment: @BillJ So what is "being" functioning as if it's not a gerund? Is it a participle? Sorry, I'm still confused.

Comment: @StuartF Question (2) is really the only one I'm concerned with. I only mentioned the software (and I'm now sorry I did) because they are what made me initially doubt myself. I didn't realise that the use of such writing platforms was so maligned.

Comment: @JJ_Doogal Traditional grammar classifies it as a present participle. Modern grammar simply lumps both _ing_ forms together, calling them 'gerund-participles".

Comment: @BillJ So if it's a participle, isn't it categorically wrong to use "your"? The only grammatical option would be "you". But I'm struggling to understand how "being" is not functioning as a noun in my sentence. Are there any clues to look out for that tell you whether an -ing verb is a gerund or a participle?

Comment: @JJ_Doogal No, it's not wrong. As I said, the genitive pronoun "your" in your example does not express possession as it would if it were a determiner in NP structure. Here it functions as subject in the clause "your being offended", where it is interchangeable with the nominative case pronoun "you". The choice depends on style, with genitive "your" being characteristic of a fairly formal style.

Comment: @BillJ So if, traditionally, "being" is classed as a present participle, does that mean it's sometimes OK to use a possessive, or genitive, pronoun before a participle?

Comment: Compare: “It's hard for us to both take our own car with **yours broken** like that" and “It's hard for us to both take our own car with **yours being broken** like that". Only the possessive pronoun *yours* works before the participle in either of those two, not things like *you* or *your*.

Comment: @JJ_Doogal Yes, both are fine: it's a matter of style. Note that the genitive is somewhat formal and rather old-fashioned. Many speakers, especially younger ones, would always use a nominative pronoun, in this case "you".

Comment: @BillJ Can you think of any example sentences where "being" **is** used as a gerund instead of an auxiliary verb?

Comment: @JJ_Doogal My advice to you is to forget the traditional contrast between gerund and present participle, just as modern grammar does. It's not important. The only thing that you need to know is that it's a verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence in question

> - *I can't prevent your being offended.*

is certainly grammatical, and, as @Billj points out, it's grammatical whether or not the subject of *being offended* is *you* or *your*. So that's one of the questions answered. Forget Google Docs and Grammarly; they're not competent at English grammar, [let alone](https://user.phil-fak.uni-duesseldorf.de/%7Efilip/fillmore+88.pdf) authoritative.

The other one is whether "*being* is functioning as a gerund here." *Being* is an auxiliary verb in the present participle verb form (the one that's [inflected](https://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Inflection.pdf) with {`-ING`}), and it's followed by the predicate *offended*, which is the main verb of the clause, and in the past participle verb form (the one inflected with {`-EN₁`}). A form of *be* is required as an auxiliary verb for both the Passive construction

- *He **was offended** by the show, but he calmed down quickly*

and a predicate adjective

- *He was never happy, always offended; he died of terminal glowering.*

In this case, you can't tell the difference, and it doesn't matter anyway, since *be* is the auxiliary either way.

The **form** of *being* does make a difference, though. It's not correct to say that *being* is a gerund. Gerunds are clauses, not words. So the question should be whether the whole clause is a gerund clause.

Even though some might say this isn't a gerund, I would. English gerunds are complement clauses with certain characteristics.

> (Incidentally, I use the word *complement* **only** for argument noun clauses;
> always clauses, always noun clauses, always argument nouns. That's ***my*** usage.)
> They're one of four English complement clause types:
>
> 1. Gerund (untensed)
> 2. Infinitive (untensed)
> 3. *That*-clauses (tensed)
> 4. *Wh*-clauses (tensed)

The gerund construction is marked by one of two Complementizers, called

- POSS-*ing* (which means "Possessive subject plus {`-ING`} verb form", like ***your** being offended*)
- ACC-*ing* (which means "Accusative subject plus {`-ING`} verb form", like ***you** being offended*)

Either form is correct, and yes, you can call the whole clause *your being offended* a gerund clause, if it matters to anyone. Though it's incorrect to say that *being* is the gerund here -- *being* is only the verb that bears the {`-ING`} gerund complement marker. The whole clause is the Gerund, and the whole Gerund clause is the direct object of the main verb *can't prevent*.

Comment: If I say: Playing is fun. Is the word "playing" a gerund clause? I cannot wrap my head around the idea that a single word is a clause.

Comment: @Lambie That's not a gerund, it's a noun: *Careful playing is allowed.* Gerunds are only ever verbs, so if you want a gerund, you'd need *Playing cards irresponsibly is fun* — which is not to be confused with  *Pretty playing cards are hard to come by* nor with *Carefree playing children are happier that way.*

Comment: @Lambie If _Leave!_ can be a whole sentence -- all that's left of a verb plus an "understood" second-person subject -- why can't a gerund or a participle do the same thing? It's normal. Right? (note the _Isn't that_ which was deleted)

Comment: @tchrist Oh, playing is a noun. Then you say: gerunds are only ever verbs. I say this: playing is a noun but it is gerund noun. Not a regular noun, as it were. That said, I was told by another linguist who shall not be named that playing is a gerund clause.

Comment: @JohnLawler I personally believe that imperatives are whole sentences. Yes. But  I don't think in "Playing is fun" that playing is gerund clause. "Playing tennis is fun". There "playing tennis" would be.

Comment: Quite often you can't tell whether a word represents a phrase or a clause without further evidence. Language has no meaning in itself, especially language that's only written.

Comment: @JohnLawler Indeed. But I'm assuming spoken utterances, oeuf corse. I think my "Playing is fun." is pretty clear. I am not posting on Instagram here. [[And I wish, (not directed at you), that others would spare me basic English lessons. It's insulting.]] My very first comment was sarcastic because for me playing is a noun and the subject of the sentence. It is not a gerund clause.

Comment: Yes, that's the way you meant it and heard it and typed it; but as soon as it's written it's silent and anybody else can hear it differently. So we often aren't understood the way we intend to be.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you for writing this answer. I'm confused because most online sources do refer to single words as gerunds.

Comment: "Playing" in "Playing is fun" is strictly speaking ambiguous between a verb and a noun, but verb is the more salient interpretation (“To play is fun”). Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in "occasional playing".